# How to change the order of fields in an already opened TADODataSet?

Tags: delphi, ado

I have a `TADODataSet` that loads some columns from the DB (a SP, but that does not matter). e.g:

```
SELECT A, B, C, D FROM Foo
```

Now, **after** I open the dataset, Is it possible to change the order  of fields (or swap them) in that `TADODataSet` so that it will contain e.g:

```
C, D, A, B
```

I want to do it without changing the command text itself.
Is it possible?

Comment: Can't you adapt the code that is reliant on this order, to effect the change?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I pass the dataset to an "export to excel" routine which exports the dataset as is in the order of fields it gets. I could pass on, the order *I want* to that process, and handle it there (which I prefer not to), I'm just curios if that is possible.

Comment: Passing the order seems like the easiest way to go, by some considerable distance

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, It might be, but then I'll need to patch a third party component which I rather not.

Comment: If you create persistent fields, you can change the .index property of each field to whatever you want it to be..

Comment: @JohnEasley:  Good idea, add as an answer.  Btw, I don't think you even need persistent TFields to do it, it works fine with dynamic (r/time) fields.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `Index` property of the `TField` class to set the desired order.

Example:

```
MyDataset.FieldByName('C').Index := 0;
MyDataset.FieldByName('D').Index := 1;
MyDataset.FieldByName('A').Index := 2;
MyDataset.FieldByName('B').Index := 3;
```

This also works if the fields are persistent:

```
MyDatasetC.Index := 0;
MyDatasetD.Index := 1;
MyDatasetA.Index := 2;
MyDatasetB.Index := 3;
```

Comment: Thank you for a very simple and elegant solution!